# Configure RemoteFTP atom package for Dreamhost SFTP

Tags: sftp, dreamhost

SFTP uploads fails when using RemoteFTP atom package with Dreamhost servers.

RemoteFTP with FTP works so I know the credentials are good.

SFTP via Filezilla works so I know the SFTP configuration on the server side is good; Filezilla prompted about the host SSH hash, which I visually confirmed/matched against the Dreamhost info.

SFTP via RemoteFTP connects but does not show the server's folders/files.
But when a file upload is attempted RemoteFTP gives error "RemoteFTP: Upload Error. No such file"

Here's a sanitized .ftpconfig:

```
{
    "protocol": "sftp",
    "host": "example.com",
    "port": 22,
    "user": "user",
    "pass": "password",
    "promptForPass": false,
    "remote": "/server-folder-name/",
    "local": "",
    "agent": "",
    "privatekey": "",
    "passphrase": "",
    "hosthash": "",
    "ignorehost": true,
    "connTimeout": 10000,
    "keepalive": 10000,
    "keyboardInteractive": false,
    "keyboardInteractiveForPass": false,
    "remoteCommand": "",
    "remoteShell": "",
    "watch": [],
     "watchTimeout": 500 
}
```

I suspected that the hosthash needed a key so I placed the Dreamhost provided fingerprint string there but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to put the entire server folder path in config file's remote field.

```
"remote": "/root/id/server-folder-name/",
```